# Move All Files in One Folder and htaccess Redirect to Them?

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, automation

I have a bunch of old static html sites. I want to install wordpress in the root on every site, but still keep the old pages. So I want to somehow automate this process for every single file:

1. Group and Move all files into a single folder (all html into \files, all media into files\media css into files\css and so on)
2. Create rules in htaccess to redirect all of the original URLs of those files to their new respective paths in the new folder. Example:

> website.com/category1/file1.html MOVED to website.com/files/file1.html

.htaccess rule:

```
RewriteRule ^category1/file1.html$ files/file1.html [L]
```

I need to do this for 30+ sites with many files. Is there a way to somehow automate this process?

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
RewriteRule ^category1/(.*)$ files/(.*) [R=301,L]
```

That will redirect `website.com/category1/file1.html` to `website.com/files/file1.html`.

Comment: I know how to do this for a single file, but I need a way to somehow automate this and do it for many files at once.

Comment: That is what it will do, it will redirect anything in the category1 folder to the files folder

Comment: category1/file1.html was just an example, I have many different categories and subfolders, subsubfolders which all contain multiple files.

Comment: Where are the categories/subfolders to be redirected to?

Comment: Well, I want to put all files from all subfolders into one folder and bulk rename them adding their respective folder/subfolder in the filename. For example file1.html from the example above becomes category1-file1.html . And then somehow create automatically htaccess rules for all files. It's that automatic process that I'm interested in. How to do it faster.